# export private key from cryptlib p15 file

Tags: export, rsa, cryptlib

I need to extract an RSA private key from a .p15 keyset that was created/maintained by CRYPTLIB. I am able to open the keyset (CryptOpenKeyset), and load it into a CRYPT_CONTEXT (cryptGetPrivateKey), but now what? Ideally I need it in PEM format for use by OPENSSL. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. As of my knowledge cryptlib has no API to export private keys. I guess this is simply for security reasons.
The only way I can think of is to write an ASN1 parser and extract and decrypt the private key from the pkcs15 structure.